# Why doesn't spread argument work for "any" type?

Tags: typescript, function, arguments, any, spread-syntax

I have the following code [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDAXIsIC2ARgKYBOANIoTnkWQJSIDeAvgFBsQIDOUi+3AOY4MYAJ6IAvMzaI5iAA4ZSGATgDaARnIAmALrk2LANxsA9GcQA5BMURxgiKAAti3OwHc4pANbcsbCjoAHShAoLBSioC9MaIFogAKs4w3IjcznAgADYAJohevlQgfDB8uXBuYADkUIGoaKHBaOGRyqppGJ3i9LH16I1hQm3R3IxdiKJifeaWAPJg2RIuqQXefgFoQZPd04PBrVEdsUA):

```
function foo(a: number, b: number) {}

const msg: any = {
    params: [1,2],
};
// None of these works:
foo(...msg.params); // This should work but it doesn't
foo(...(msg.params as any));
foo((...msg.params) as any);

// Only this works:
(foo as any)(...msg.params);
```

The error message is:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

`msg`/`msg.params` are already `any`. Why can't I use it for `spread ...` operator and pass as function argument? Isn't it the point of `any`? And why does casting the function to `any` works?

---

The forced compiled Javascript works:

```js
"use strict";
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log(a + b);
}
const msg = {
    params: [1, 2],
};
foo(...msg.params); // Logs 3 correctly
```

Comment: _"`msg` is already `any`"_ - How is this relevant for the error? `params` is not a tuple, and `foo` has no rest parameter.

Comment: How can you expect TS to verify that you pass two arguments when it doesn't know how many arguments you would pass?

Comment: And why don't any of the ["A spread argument must either have..." questions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22A+spread+argument+must+either+have+a+tuple+type+or+be+passed+to+a+rest+parameter%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) here on SO have an answer for you?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry I meant `msg.params` is `any`. An `any` type should be able to pass to anything, including as a tuple.

Comment: @VLAZ That's the point of `any`. By telling TypeScript it is `any`, I am saying "I know what I am doing, just pass it". This case is weird because `any` is not considered a tuple.

Comment: The error is not about `msg.params`, but about `foo` requiring specific number of arguments. That's why casting `foo` to `any` "works" https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUA6LAPAXIsEAWwCMBTAJwG0BdASkQG8BfAKFYgQGcpEiuA5vgCGYAJ6IAvE1aI5iAA7CKw-vioBGADQAmGltbMA3OxTosGfgIxKV-OkaA

Comment: @LukeVo No, that's not sure that's what `any` means. It's just an escape clause from the type system. It stands for *anything* which might or might not be a tuple with two items. Hence why TS cannot verify that you pass two arguments - it doesn't know how many there would be. That's even if we assume that you would give it an iterable - `msg.params` could even be a number or an object and then the code would fail at runtime. I don't have any statistics to back it up, but I think the most errors in TS come from people using `any` instead of actual types.

Comment: @AlekseyL. nice catch, I didn't know the error is due to the function, not the `msg.params`. However it still irks me that `foo` doesn't accept a spread from `any` as valid parameters.

Comment: @VLAZ good point. I concede though I think it's questionable design that `...any` does not return `any`. When I implicitly set something to `any` I already take responsibility for anything that may happen, bad code or not.

Answer (score 1):

Function `foo` is defined to expect exactly two arguments of type `number`, so typescript is preventing you from passing a different number of arguments to it.

If you cannot modify your `msg` variable to add the correct typing, then there are several ways of working around it:

1. Casting `foo` to `any` will essentially disable the typescript check, that's why you don't see an error in your example,

```
(foo as any)(...msg.params);
```

2. You can cast the argument to a tuple like `[number, number]` or even `[any, any]`,

```
foo(...(msg.params as [number, number]));
foo(...(msg.params as [any, any]));
```

3. You can pass the element directly instead of using the spread operator, like `msg.params[0]`.

```
foo(msg.params[0], msg.params[1]);
```

Here's the full [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDAXIsIC2ARgKYBOANIoTnkWQJSIDeAvgFBsQIDOUi+3AOY4MYAJ6IAvMzaI5iAA4ZSGATgDaARnIAmALrk2LANxsA9GcQA5BMURxgiKAAti3OwHc4pANbcsbCjoAHShAoLBSioC9MaIFogAKs4w3IjcznAgADYAJohevlQgfDB8uXBuYADkUIGoaKHBaOGRyqppGJ3i9LH16I1hQm3R3IxdiKJifeaWAPJg2RIuqQXefgFoQZPd04PBrVEdMwkrndnccGu+-v37LcNHAjuI6rQkFLgEH3q9pkH3Q7tZ4TdRTShTX59AFA0bqAAMBn4j2B3C0v1MHC4YF4yMEOhwTEUqI07zIlDJpD0LCkMnkxNGGm0+kMJjuTXCOhGx0xoEgsAQyFQOn22C+dFI6l+zHYQRFHKEXKeY3+wv2sJ5QA).

But ideally, `any` should not be used because it's essentially disabling the type checks and is very error-prone, like others have mentioned in the comments. The best solution is to redefine the function or the variable to the correct types — check the link I included above for one example of how to do that.